# how to copy files CMD or Powershell with condition always ignore two files

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want to copy files from a specific folder with a condition that always ignores two files until the last file.

Example: Copy file 1, next 4, next 7, next 10 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 1 item from a collection, then skip two, then repeat, use the modulo (`%`) operator to calculate every third index:

```
# Enumerate files in folder
$files = Get-ChildItem .\folder -File

# Based on the count, calculate the array indices for every 3rd file
$indices = 0..($files.Count - 1) |Where-Object { $_ % 3 -eq 0 }

# Assign every 3rd file to new array
$filesToCopy = $files[$indices]
```

Now you can copy only those files:

```
$filesToCopy |Copy-Item .\destination\
```